# How to download apps without using the store?

Tags: store, 7.8

Can we download apps or games on our PC first and then later install them through Zune? I have a Nokia Lumia 800.

Comment: why you want do that?

Answer (score 9):

This is a more general answer and doesn't work on the Lumia 800. But, if you have a device with Windows Phone 8, or higher, and an SD card slot then you can download the .xap file and install it manually.

To do so:

1. Find the application you want on http://www.windowsphone.com/
2. Click the *Download and install manually* link down the bottom-left of the page.
3. Copy the downloaded .xap file to root path your SD card.
4. Reboot your phone and wait for 1-2 minutes.
5. Open the store app on your phone and then tap SD card.
6. Select the applications that you want to install.

Comment: .Xap files can only be red by WP8 ;) WP8 is not supported by Lumia 800

Comment: Actually I believe it did work with WP 7.x on phones with an SD card slot.

Comment: Is it possible **without** a developer account?

Comment: Looks like the option is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is impossible. Your phone hasn't a SD port...so the only way is the App Store of the phone and Windowsphone.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Unless you have a developer unlocked phone, in which case you can deploy xap files (app installation files) onto your phone.

Answer (score 1):

this is not supported on 7.5 phones (not sure about 7.8). But you can install xap files if you have a developer account. You attach your deivce to your PC. unlock it through visual studio phone unlocker (it will ask you your credentials for developer account) and then deply xap files on your device. But there is limit on this. You can install max 10-15 (not sure what is exact number) on your device.